# call to `exp_member_groups` database table, which is non-existent in ExpressionEngine 6

Tags: ee6

I am getting this error message in ExpressionEngine 6 developer log.

Add-on is making a call to `exp_member_groups` database table, which is non-existent in ExpressionEngine 6. If you are site owner, try upgrading Addon to latest available version. If you are the add-on developer, update your class to use Role model.

Comment: If upgrading the add-on doesn't work, drop help@eeharbor.com an email.

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionEngine 6 introduced a new feature Member Roles. Member groups will no longer use in this version.
You will have to update the addon.
for more detail about this feature see the documentation.
[Member Roles](https://expressionengine.com/feature-callout/member-roles)

Here is the guide to [call MemberGroup model with Role model.](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/v6-add-on-migration.html#replace-calls-to-membergroup-model-with-role-model)